# How to parse XML using SP_XML_PREPAREDOCUMENT for UTF-8 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing

This is main procedure:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GHA_SAP_GetResponseXML]
    @xmlINVDetails ntext
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @XMLData XML, @DatVal nvarchar(max),
            @authenticationCode varchar(500), @messageId varchar(50)

    SELECT @DatVal = @xmlINVDetails

    SELECT @XMLData = SUBSTRING(@DatVal, CHARINDEX('>', @DatVal) + 1, LEN(@DatVal))

    SELECT 
        @authenticationCode = Node.Data.value('(authenticationCode)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
        @messageId = Node.Data.value('(messageId)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
    FROM
        @XMLData.nodes('/BASSAPRequest') Node(Data) 
    
    DECLARE @intPointer int
    
    DECLARE @tblFSU Table
                    (
                         [Month] varchar(5), 
                         [Year] INT, 
                         InvType varchar(10)
                    )

    EXEC SP_XML_PREPAREDOCUMENT @intPointer output, @xmlINVDetails

    INSERT INTO @tblFSU ([Month], [Year], InvType)
        SELECT [Month], [Year], InvType             
        FROM OPENXML (@intPointer, 'BASSAPRequest', 2)   
             WITH (
                      [Month] varchar(5), 
                      [Year] INT, 
                      InvType varchar(10)
                  )
  
    --select * from @tblFSU

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #FSU_FOR_XML

    DECLARE @month int, @year int,@invoType varchar(10), 
            @FSUCount bigint, @Airline_code varchar(2)

    SELECT @month = [Month] FROM @tblFSU
    SELECT @year = [Year] FROM @tblFSU
    SELECT @invoType = invType FROM @tblFSU
END
```

When I am executing this procedure, I get this error:

```
GHA_SAP_GetResponseXML
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BASSAPRequest>
  <InvType>036</InvType>
  <Year>2021</Year>
  <Month>03</Month>
</BASSAPRequest>'
```

The I got the following errors:

> The XML parse error 0xc00ce56f occurred on line number 1, near the XML text ""
>
> Msg 6602, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_xml_preparedocument, Line 27
> The error description is 'Switch from current encoding to specified encoding not supported.'.
>
> Msg 8179, Level 16, State 5, Procedure GHA_SAP_GetResponseXML, Line 51
> Could not find prepared statement with handle 0.

Comment: Why are you using `SP_XML_PREPAREDOCUMENT` at all here and not just XQuery?

Comment: If you're using an `nvarchar(max)` input parameter then why does it still have `encoding="UTF-8"`? Seems like you need to fix your XML.

Comment: what i need to do. please help me.

Comment: You'd be better off explaining what you *actually* want to achieve. Sample data and expected results willl help us help you.

Comment: i have edited please check

Comment: You don't appear to have `authenticationCode` or `messageId` nodes in your XML. Also you aren't actually returning any results

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why you are using `ntext` rather than `nvarchar(max)`, why you are not using `varchar` with a UTF-8 collation if you have UTF-8 XML, and why you are trying to select nodes that don't exist.

Be that as it may, I advise you to avoid the `openxml` and associated procedures, and just use `.nodes` and `.value`

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GHA_SAP_GetResponseXML]
  @xmlINVDetails nvarchar(max)
AS

SELECT
  authenticationCode = Node.Data.value('(authenticationCode/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
  messageId          = Node.Data.value('(messageId/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
  Month              = Node.Data.value('(Month/text())[1]', 'varchar(5)'),
  Year               = Node.Data.value('(Year/text())[1]', 'int'),
  InvType            = Node.Data.value('(InvType/text())[1]', 'varchar(10)')
FROM (VALUES( CAST(CAST(@xmlINVDetails COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8 AS varchar(max)) AS xml) )) v(XmlData)
CROSS APPLY v.XmlData.nodes('/BASSAPRequest') Node(Data);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=82e5f3072d32231067cb337aa442dbc5)

Result:

| authenticationCode | messageId | Month | Year | InvType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *null* | *null* | 03 | 2021 | 036 |

Comment: when i have used varchar(max) instead of nvarchar(max) then my error resolved.

Comment: Indeed, but you still shouldn't use `openxml`